# VSCode selectively remove yellow squiggly suggestion

Tags: visual-studio, settings, svelte

I'm finding troubleshooting VSCode incredibly frustrating. There seems to have been some changes to it in the last few months/years that make past advice totally irrelevant. Eg, searching 'squigg' (for error squiggly) brings up nothing. So many sites seem to point to different approaches to making changes to the settings. For example, how do I directly edit the settings to change the HEX value of the colour? Can't find it anywhere.

I'm using SVELTE and I hate some of the recommendations, especially when it says to use `on:blur` instead of `on:change` on a `select` element, since in fact the functionality is totally different. So now a large chunk of code has this obnoxious yellow squiggly under it that makes it much harder to read. I could happily disable all squigglies but for the life of me can't navigate around their ridiculous settings menu.

The only place seems to be `Workspace>Extensions` but there are only references to CSS, LESS, SCSS etc and nothing that tackles the suggestions given to me about how to type my SVELTE code.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are talking about the A11y warnings of the Svelte compiler.

If you want to disable them on a case-by-case basis, you can do so by placing a comment above the html block which looks like this: `<!-- svelte-ignore <the warning code> -->`. Assuming you have installed the [Svelte for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=svelte.svelte-vscode) extension, you can see the warning code when hovering the warning. It's the last thing in braces. For your select example, it would be `<!-- svelte-ignore a11y-no-onchange -->`. You can also just use the quick fix suggestion the extension provides you which will do this automatically for you.
Note that not all warnings can be disabled this way.

If you want to disable this globally, adjust the `Svelte: Compiler Warnings` setting in VSCode. You can find it by searching for "Svelte warnings" in your settings GUI. `svelte-check` also has such an option, it's called `--compiler-warnings`.

Comment: Welcome! If that solved your question, please consider marking this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Oh yeah, I upticked but forgot to check